# Login in a popup vs sidebar

Tags: website-design, login, placement

I have been wondering why most of the popular websites go for displaying the login form on a popup or a separate page vs having it in the sidebar.

One of the very few of them that has the login form in the sidebar is reddit, and I think it fits really well when login is not mandatory to use the website functionality.

Why there aren't more websites with this approach?

Comment: There is a large amount of context that is missing in your question. What would you see if you didn't log into Facebook, or similar site? Help us understand the specific types of workflows you are interested in when using one login metaphor over another.

Answer (score 3):

Here are reasons why it is in a popup, under most circumstances:

Login is a one-time-per-visit action (if even that) - do it and you're done. Because of that, no need to take up real estate all the time with it. In addition, once you have logged in, do the fields remain? Likely not.

Once logged in, the interface updates to a logged-in experience (new functions, new features). A popup or modal view stops you from seeing or doing anything else, so the experience is like lowering the curtain, changing the scenery, and raising the curtain. Otherwise, the user may not recognize that anything has changed.

The convention is to hide it behind a login/account recognition button in the top right, and people like this predictable placement.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an easy question to answer.  Here are my guess:
+ Use cases for login after session ends.
+ Technology used.
+ Usually, banking or any user sensitive sites require you to not to see any aspect of the user's information that is why you have the entire new login page.
+ In site where you can browse you have to login only when you have to comment or favorite something. This login could be a pop-up or a new page. The use of pop-up is used when you are not showing any marketing Ads.